# Members location sortable based on UK Postcode

Tags: search

I have just come back to creating WordPress sites after a few years away from it.

I am trying to create a site that has members and currently trying a few membership plugins.

The issue I have is that I would like to have the member's location (first half of UK Postcode) and be able to do various searches based on this data. Does anyone have a clue how to go about this?

eg: members in a certain radius, members of the same postcode, members distance from each other.

Comment: what you're describing would need to be opt in only under UK data protection law. the searching within a radius in miles would be impossible with just the first half of the code unless you're happy with a low level of accuracy, some postcodes are for small dense places, but others cover huge areas. At a minimum you'd need a lat/long for each postcode areas centre, assuming the areas are not weird shapes which a lot of them are. Figuring those parts out has nothing to do with WordPress though. I also removed the request for tutorials/recommendations as that would get your Q closed as offtopic